# How do I place a hidden input field inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, view, popup, textarea

I want to make a popup text box that shows source codes from the textarea in the popup as a web page wile at the same time it will **not** show the print button codes in the textarea because that text is meant to be as functions for the popup only. As you can see my textarea content has both javascript and html who needs to be hidden from the textarea, but at the same time needs to be inside the text area for the popup to work.

This means I can not put them outside the textarea because then that function will not show in the popup window who will show everything that is in the textarea of the web editor editor unless the popup is made to target a div that holds the textarea and and not the textarea directly. Even so that presents a problem as the textarea will not anymore be converted into a web page when getting the popup.

I am using this textarea for my popup:

```
    <textarea name="textfield" cols="107" rows="31" id="CodeExample" wrap="soft" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); resize: none;" placeholder="The is Source Codes here"><script language="Javascript">
    function printit(){
    if (NS) {
        window.print() ;
    } else {
        var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT id="WebBrowser1" width=0 height=0 CLASSid="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
        WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 2);//Use a 1 vs. a 2 for a prompting dialog box    WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
    }
    }
    </script>
    <script language="Javascript">
    var NS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape");
    var VERSION = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
    if (VERSION > 3) {
        document.write('<form><input type=button value="Print this Page" name="Print" onClick="printit()" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font: bold 11px Arial, Sans-Serif;"></form>');
    }
    </script></textarea>
<br>
    <!-- Run Textarea field in popup BEGIN -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var win = null;
    function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll) {
    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
    settings =
    'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
    win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
    if (window.focus) {win.focus()}
    var t = document.form1.textfield.value; 
    win.document.write(t);
    }
    </script>
    <input type = "button" value = "Preview" name = "preview" onclick = "NewWindow('','myPop','500','400','yes')">
    <!-- Run Textarea field in popup END -->
```

So now what I want is for the print button codes to not be visible in the textarea, but that they are visible as a print button when the popup button is run. So that the print button adds to the visible source codes added into the box by the web designer.

Comment: It makes no sense to put other `<input>` elements inside a `<textarea>`.

Comment: It makes sense and forget it, I just found the answer 1 minutes ago.
I will post the answer to my own question now and you will see what I was looking for and why.

Comment: If you are making a web editor online as I am with preview function then it all of a sudden it is making sense. Because you will want to preview your codes that you text inside the textarea box and when previewing you will also want that the textarea box shows some extra buttons such as print the preview you made.
Perfect to test a design or a page and such and then print it out by the click of one button on the popup generated by the textarea box.
Look at the solution I found and test it yourself and see what I mean and why.
It will work with any HTML, CSS and JS source codes.

Comment: I guess the main thing I would *not* do is use a `<textarea>` as the place to store the content. Also, I wouldn't put `<script>` tags in there like that; I'd use external scripts for all the behaviors.

Comment: Yes I actually do use external scripts. But for the sake of having it tested easily for them who try this out online I used an internal script. 
Also on the web page I am making one can view all the source codes of any function if they wish too.
But since I hate redundant repeating the same codes for just to show them off, I made another function that will show it in a floating window the source codes of that specific web page file of the function.
There for to have external files will be a pain in the ass to make that source code viewer work, even though I am sure it could work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**When I posted this question I found no answer no were on the entire internet.**

After fiddling with it for a long time I posted the question here. And by luck I found an answer of how to do it after a few minute of after posted the question. I will not delete the question since I am the FIRST on the internet to find and answer to this question.

**Solution:**
I solved the problem by simply making a hidden textarea linked to the input popup javascript who is also linked to the visible textera. That way what ever is put inside the visble textarea will come up in the popup and so will also the function from hidden in the hidden textarea come on the same popup when clicked on the "Preview" button.

You can put any HTML, CSS or JavaScript code inside the visible and inside the hidden textarea wile having all the input codes hidden from the visible textarea it but active when the popup is turned on.

```
<form name = "form1">

<textarea name="textfield" cols="107" rows="31" id="CodeExample" wrap="soft" style="font-size:12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); resize: none;" placeholder="Put your Source Codes here">
</textarea>

<textarea hidden="on" name="textfield2" cols="1" rows="1" id="CodeExample2">
<script language="Javascript">
function printit(){
if (NS) {
    window.print() ;
} else {
    var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT id="WebBrowser1" width=0 height=0 CLASSid="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
    WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 2);//Use a 1 vs. a 2 for a prompting dialog box    WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
}
}
</script>
<script language="Javascript">
var NS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape");
var VERSION = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
if (VERSION > 3) {
    document.write('<form><input type=button value="Print this Page" name="Print" onClick="printit()" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font: bold 11px Arial, Sans-Serif;"></form>');
}
</script>
</textarea>

<br>

<!-- Run Textarea field in popup BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var win = null;
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll) {
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)/2 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings =
'height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',resizable'
win = window.open(mypage,myname,settings);
if (window.focus) {win.focus()}
var t1 = document.form1.textfield.value;
var t2 = document.form1.textfield2.value;       
win.document.write(t1);
win.document.write(t2);
}
</script>
<input type = "button" value = "Preview" name = "preview" onclick = "NewWindow('','myPop','500','400','yes')">
<!-- Run Textarea field in popup END -->

</form>
```

**NOTE:**

If you are making a web editor online as I am with preview function then it all of a sudden it is making sense. Because you will want to preview your codes that you text inside the textarea box and when previewing you will also want that the textarea box shows some extra buttons such as print the preview you made. Perfect to test a design or a page and such and then print it out by the click of one button on the popup generated by the textarea box. Look at the solution I found and test it yourself and see what I mean and why. It will work with any HTML, CSS and JS source codes.

Test it yourself if you do not understand why it was needed and how it works.